# Como puedo mostrar todas deducciones de un solo empleado

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-5

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

esta es mi vista actual que me muestra las deducciones de los empleados lo que necesito es mostrar todas las deducciones de un  empleado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

si puede ver aqui muestra todas, lo que quiero es que me muestre todas del empleado 2390 por ejemplo que es el que tiene mas

```
SELECT dbo.Tbl_DetalleDeduccionesEmpleado.DetDedEmpFecha, dbo.Tbl_DetalleDeduccionesEmpleado.DetDedEmpValor, dbo.Tbl_Empleado.EmpNombre, dbo.Tbl_Empleado.EmpApellido, dbo.Tbl_HistorialLaboral.AgeId, 
dbo.Tbl_HistorialLaboral.AreId, dbo.Tbl_HistorialLaboral.HisLabEstadoEmpleado, dbo.Tbl_Deducciones.DedDescripcion, dbo.Tbl_DetalleDeduccionesEmpleado.DedId, dbo.Tbl_DetalleDeduccionesEmpleado.EmpId, 
dbo.Tbl_Deducciones.DedTipo FROM dbo.Tbl_DetalleDeduccionesEmpleado INNER JOIN
dbo.Tbl_Empleado ON dbo.Tbl_DetalleDeduccionesEmpleado.EmpId = dbo.Tbl_Empleado.EmpId INNER JOIN
dbo.Tbl_HistorialLaboral ON dbo.Tbl_Empleado.EmpId = dbo.Tbl_HistorialLaboral.EmpId INNER JOIN
dbo.Tbl_Deducciones ON dbo.Tbl_DetalleDeduccionesEmpleado.DedId = dbo.Tbl_Deducciones.DedId
```

---

perfecto Ricardo muchas gracias..

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Marco, creo que sería de gran ayuda que ademas de las imágenes, también agregues el código de tu consulta para poder analizarlo mas detalladamente.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Y no alcanza con filtrarla con un where? no entiendo esta pregunta si no.

Comment: perfecto muchas gracias

Comment: Ricardo ya subi el codigo

Comment: @MarcoEufragio vuelvo a la pregunta original. Y un where en la consulta no alcanza?

Comment: Edite mi respuesta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que necesitas es agregarle el **Where** para decirle que necesitas solo los datos de ese empleado:

```
SELECT dbo.Tbl_DetalleDeduccionesEmpleado.DetDedEmpFecha, dbo.Tbl_DetalleDeduccionesEmpleado.DetDedEmpValor, dbo.Tbl_Empleado.EmpNombre, dbo.Tbl_Empleado.EmpApellido, dbo.Tbl_HistorialLaboral.AgeId, 
dbo.Tbl_HistorialLaboral.AreId, dbo.Tbl_HistorialLaboral.HisLabEstadoEmpleado, dbo.Tbl_Deducciones.DedDescripcion, dbo.Tbl_DetalleDeduccionesEmpleado.DedId, dbo.Tbl_DetalleDeduccionesEmpleado.EmpId, 
dbo.Tbl_Deducciones.DedTipo FROM dbo.Tbl_DetalleDeduccionesEmpleado INNER JOIN
dbo.Tbl_Empleado ON dbo.Tbl_DetalleDeduccionesEmpleado.EmpId = dbo.Tbl_Empleado.EmpId INNER JOIN
dbo.Tbl_HistorialLaboral ON dbo.Tbl_Empleado.EmpId = dbo.Tbl_HistorialLaboral.EmpId INNER JOIN
dbo.Tbl_Deducciones ON dbo.Tbl_DetalleDeduccionesEmpleado.DedId = dbo.Tbl_Deducciones.DedId Where dbo.Tbl_Empleado.EmpId = 2390
```

Comment: como podria mostrar las deducciones que tiene ese mismo empleado en un rango de fecha , por ejemplo del '2018/05/01' AND '2018/05/08'

Comment: usa el BETWEEN '2018/05/01' AND '2018/05/08'

Comment: Brother como podría mostrar todas las deducciones aunque  el no tenga un valor en las otras, no se si viste el resultado que me dio, me sale donde tiene valor. bueno si esque se puede hacer eso

Comment: Si lo que quieres es mostrar los campos que son nulos en algunas tablas, necesitas utilizar LEFT JOIN en lugar de INNER JOIN.

Comment: ok me las muestra, pero si en ese rango de fecha hay dos deducciones del mismo nombre que solo aparezca solo una , osea que las sume y solo mueste 1  como podria hacer eso

Comment: Si tienen exactamente los mismo datos en ambas filas (si están repetidos), puedes usar un Group By y pones primero el DedId, me tienes algo a ciegas aquí, es difícil poder ayudarte. Saludos.

Comment: tienes mucha razón, tendría que formular otra pregunta , porque en realidad lo que necesito es que me muestre todas las deducciones de los empleados en un rango de fechas